# Retrieve data from a stored object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use [MMKV dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mmkv) to store and retrieve data put in Storage. In this case I want to store the data of a user. But I have a problem when I want to retrieve this data as an object. Indeed, when I `console.log` my hook `currentUserData` I have all the data like this:

```
{"user":{"id":9,"email":"userEmail","first_name":"firstNameUser","last_name":"","zipcode":"","city":"userCity","address":""},"token":"tokenUser"}
```

But when I `console.log(currenUserData.user)` or `console.log(currentUserData.user.email)` for example it puts me undefined, I don't understand why.

Here is my code :

```js
import {MMKV, useMMKVObject, useMMKVString} from 'react-native-mmkv';

const storage = new MMKV();

export default function HomeLogin() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState({});
  const [currentUserData, setCurrentUserData] = useState({});
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const jsonValue = storage.getString('user');
    const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(jsonValue) || {};
    setCurrentUserData(parsedUserData);
  }, [currentUserData]);

  /* I have tried this too but the same result : error currentDataUser.user.city and currentData.user.first_name is undefined
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const getUserData = async () => {
      try {
        /!*const jsonValue = storage.getString('user');
        const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(jsonValue) || {};
        setCurrentUserData(parsedUserData);*!/
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${APIKEY}&q=${parsedUserData?.user?.city}&aqi=no&lang=fr`,
        );
        setCurrentData(response.data.current.condition);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false);
        alert(e);
      }
    };
    getUserData();
  }, []);*/

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#3c693d" />
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginTop: 50,
            }}>
            <View
              style={{flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 20, marginTop: 20}}>
              <Image
                style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
                source={{
                  uri: `https:${
                    Object.keys(currentUserData).length > 0
                      ? currentData.icon
                      : ''
                  }`,
                }}
              />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              Bienvenue, {'\n'}{' '}
              <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                {Object.keys(currentUserData).length > 0
                  ? currentUserData.user.first_name
                  : ''}
              </Text>
            </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Just a thought, but it looks like you're saving the data as an array.  Try telling your parser to use the first element.

Comment: @JohnLord Thanks for your response, I tried but the same error : `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'currentUserData[0].user')`

Comment: i was thinking like this:
 const jsonValue = storage.getString('user');
        const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(jsonValue[0]) || {};
        setCurrentUserData(parsedUserData);

Comment: @JohnLord I tried too : `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'currentUserData.user[0]')`
I don't understand why it does this...

Comment: look at my edit and try that.   It looks like you tried something i ended up deleting.